# "Next unhandled conflict" icon disappeared in VSCode Merge Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the VSCode Merge Editor, the button to go to the next unhandled conflict (the down arrow) disappeared (the capability still exists, hidden behind the meatball menu). I probably inadvertently did something. How do I restore it?

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75813448/11107541 maybe a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
Right click the meatball menu TWICE, and then re-check the unchecked selection.

Right click meatball once:

[image]

Right click meatball a second time:

[image]