# Terminal Add button or "+" in vscode is gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

My terminal dropdown / add / `+` button is gone. I can't change my terminal.

This happened after I mis-clicked something

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc5Tm.png)

now I can't change my terminal

I hope I can show my terminal add button / dropdown / `+` button.

Comment: huh. what if you restart VS Code? Any recollection of what you "misclicked"?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on one of the other icons there, like the garbage can, and choose `New Terminal` from the dropdown.

And the command `Views: Reset All Menus` would bring it back as well.